# How to write a XPath that selects a attribute value in two different levels

Tags: java, html, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

There are 2 tables and I need to select the "date1" text which might be in the tr/td/a in the 1st table or tr/td in the 2nd table. How to write a xpath for this kind of scenario?

```
<div>
    <table>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td id="1">
                <a style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;" onclick="return" class="PTL"> </a>
             </td>  
             <td id="1">
                <a style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;" onclick="return" class="PTL">date1</a>
             </td>  
             <td id="1">
                <a style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;" onclick="return" class="PTL">date1</a>
             </td>
             <td id="1">
                <a style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;" onclick="return" class="PTL">date2</a>
             </td>
             <td id="1">
                <a style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;" onclick="return" class="PTL">date3</a>
             </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td id="1" style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;" class="PTCH"> </td>
              <td id="1" style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;" class="PTCH">date1</td>
              <td id="1" style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;" class="PTCH">date2</td>
              <td id="1" style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;" class="PTCH">date3</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried this but this select the entire row. I want to select a specific column

```
xpath=(//table)[2]//tr[td[contains(text(),'date1') and not(text()=' ')] or td/a[contains(text(),'date1') and not(text()=' ')]]
```

Comment: Down-vote from me. No evidence you've tried anything yourself or researched this topic. This question is just a requirements dump.

Comment: I did lot of research on this but unable to find a solution. Can u pls look into this

Comment: @udeshplus You say that you want to select the `date1` text, but in your attempts, you are selecting a `tr` element. What is it that you actually want to do? Please describe your requirment clearly.

Comment: @ JLRishe I want to select the "date1" text. In my case there are two tables. 1st table "date1" text in following object path "tbody/tr/td/a" and 2nd table in following object path "tbody/tr/td". So i need to write one xpath to select "date1" text for both scenarios using "or" condition. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the answer you posted, you are actually selecting a `td` element. You say you want to select the "date1" text, but there is no point in selecting the text if you already know what it is.

The following is a simpler approach to what you've posted:

```
//table//tr/td[contains(., 'date1')]
```

Or if you only want to include the first table (as you're doing in your post):

```
(//table)[1]//tr/td[contains(., 'date1')]
```

Regarding your comment below, if you want to find a value that is in an attribute, do this:

```
(//table)[1]//tr/td[descendant-or-self::*[contains(@style, 'bold')]]
```

Or if you want to select the actual element that has the `style` attribute with `bold` in it:

```
(//table)[1]//tr/td/descendant-or-self::*[contains(@style, 'bold')]
```

Comment: Your answer is working for the text-content but if I tried using style attribute, like this it won't work. 

`xpath=(//table)[1]//tr/td[contains(., 'bold')]`

But using my solution this works. Please clarify.

`xpath=(//table)[1]//tr/td[contains(@style,'bold') and not(text()=' ') or a[contains(@style,'bold') and not(text()=' ')]]`

Answer (score 0):

//a 
you can copy this into text file and change it to html use firebug to find the path and xpath checker (Fire Fox plugin ) for beginner it is very easy

Answer (score 0):

After number of attempts I came up with this and its working as I needed. Thanks all.

```
xpath=(//table)[1]//tr/td[contains(text(),'date1') and not(text()=' ') or a[contains(text(),'date1') and not(text()=' ')]]
```